# c# code to create a new windows form every click of button

Tags: c#, winforms

I need help on creating a new form when I click a button.

For example, I have a form named `create_form` then has a button named `Create`. What I want is to create a form every time I click the `Create` button, and the forms created will be independent from each other.

I don't want to create a lot of form in Visual Studio like "Form1, Form2, Form3, Form4..etc.." and call each one every time the button is clicked. Then I'd have to be able to create another form in Visual Studio for each time I wanted to click the button, even if I click it 20 times or more. All I want is to create one windows form (`Form3` for example) then every time I click the `Create` button it will just call it and create a new instance of that form. If I click 20 times then there should be 20 forms created and independent from each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you already have a form named `Form3`, here is what your button click event will look like:

```
//use this so you have an easy reference to each of your forms
private myForms As new List<Form3>();

protected void Create_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     var form = new Form3();
     myForms.Add(form);
     form.Show();
}
```

Comment: @user3571238 If the answer works you should check it as such.

Comment: I did checked it but vote from me that has reputation less than 15 will not be viewed I think. Sorry I'm newbie.